threejs position attribute, why does it compute repetitive vertexes?
while working on getting the geometry vertexes from a mesh, I encountered the following discovery:
My boxgeometry is supposed to have only 8 vertexes, however the threejs computation delivers 24 of them after transforming the local coordinates to the world system.
const boxMesh = object3d.children[1];
const positionAttrib =
  boxMesh.geometry.getAttribute("position");

let vertexes = [];
for (
  let index = 0;
  index < positionAttrib.count;
  index++
) {
  const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  vertex.fromBufferAttribute(
    positionAttrib,
    index
  );
  boxMesh.localToWorld(vertex);

  const s = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.005);
  const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "red",
  });
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(s, mat);
  mesh.position.set(
    vertex.x,
    vertex.y,
    vertex.z
  );
  boundingBoxUtils.bbScene.add(mesh)

  vertexes.push(vertex);
}
console.log(vertexes);



as you can see in the images, I end up with 24 vertexes. However, if I add this manual filter, I manage to remove the repetitive vertexes:
  // const isRepetitiveVertex = vertexes.some(
  //   (x) => x.distanceTo(vertex) < 0.01
  // );

  // if (isRepetitiveVertex) continue;

So why does threejs is computing repetitive vertexes?

The reason for this is vertex normal indexing.
Shapes are drawn as tringles.
Triangles have 3 vertices (the position attribute, which I will call "vertices" from here on). They also have 3 normal values, one for each vertex. The normal is to define the direction the triangle is facing at each vertex, and is most commonly used by the shaders affecting the lighting.
The geometry definition for a single triangle would have two buffers:
vertex: [ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3 ]
normal: [ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3 ]

A square plane (like the side of a cube) is composed of two triangles. If you define each triangle individually, you would have 6 vertices and 6 normals. So, instead, we define the 4 vertices and 4 normals that make up the corners, and add an index list that provides GL with an ordered list of the indices of the vertices/normals that compose each triangle. (We won't get into "winding order" here, but it's a good topic to understand.)
You might already be seeing another inefficiency: If all the normals are the same, why not just use one, or have them indexed separately? Because normals could be different, even if the vertex value is the equal. Remember that normals are often used for lighting calculations: The same normals for equivalent vertices would result in smooth blending, while different normals may result in a hard edge.
The important concept here is that vertices and normals are paired, and can't be separated nor indexed separately.
The geometry definition for a single square would have three buffers:
vertex: [ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4 ]
normal: [ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4 ]
index : [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 ]

A cube has 6 sides, so it's easy to see that there can be 24 indexed vertices/normals. But THAT seems inefficient because there are only 8 corners, right?
Well, remember that the vertex/normal pairs can't be separated, which means each of the 6 sides, each facing in a different direction, needs the full plane definition. You could index out the vertices, but then the normals would be wrong. And if the normals are wrong, then in most cases you'll get undesired rendering artifacts.

Appreciate the response, give me some time to process this information to mark it as solved hehe
